# Merge node with NULL property Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to do something like

```
MERGE (c:C {p1: 123})
WHERE p2 IS NULL
RETURN c
```

i.e., try to match a node with label `C` with value `123` for property `p1` and with property `p2` not set. And while that syntax is okay if I use `MATCH` instead of `MERGE`, the way it's written it doesn't work. Is there another way to write it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using `WITH` keyword:

```
MERGE (c:C {p1: 123})
WITH c WHERE c.p2 IS NULL
RETURN c
```

Below `WITH` statement you will have only `C`'s that have p1 = 123 and no `p2` whether they matched or created.