# Inserting General Entities in Neo4j Using MERGE: Matching Issue with Similar Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j to relate data extracted from official government documents, and I'm developing a Python program to automate this process. However, there are cases where a more general entity is extracted, like `(:Position {symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", effective: false})`. When I attempt to insert it into the database using a query like:

```
MERGE (c:Position {symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", effective: false})
RETURN ID(c)
```

The `MERGE` clause ends up matching a node of the type `(:Position {symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", location:"zzz", effective: false})`.

How can I modify my Cypher query to ensure that the node `(c:Position {symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", effective: false})` is inserted into the database? In this case, using `CREATE` alone is not sufficient, as similar nodes might be extracted again.

I encountered a similar issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190061/merge-node-with-null-property-neo4j). However, the provided solution doesn't work in my case because the `WHERE` clause returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` is not suitable for your use case. Here is one way to ensure a `Position` node with the exact set of properties you want exists. The query assumes that the desired properties are passed to the query in a `props` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) (e.g., `{symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", location:"zzz", effective: false}`)

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Position)
WHERE PROPERTIES(p) = $props
CALL {
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NULL
  CREATE (q:Position)
  SET q = $props
  RETURN q AS result
  UNION
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NOT NULL
  RETURN p AS result
}
RETURN ID(result)
```

Comment: This works when I am dealing with a single parameter, but it creates duplicates nodes with the use of UNWIND. I made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168864/using-unwind-to-insert-general-entities-neo4j)  asking for a solution to this problem

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78169063/974731) to your new post.