# Using UNWIND to insert general entities in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A while ago I made [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77245127/inserting-general-entities-in-neo4j-using-merge-matching-issue-with-similar-nod) about a matching issue with similar nodes when inserting general entities in the Neo4J database. The proposed solution was not to use MERGE and instead do something like:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Position)
WHERE PROPERTIES(p) = $props
CALL {
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NULL
  CREATE (q:Position)
  SET q = $props
  RETURN q AS result
  UNION
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NOT NULL
  RETURN p AS result
}
RETURN ID(result)
```

Now I want to use UNWIND to create multiple entites at once like this

```
UNWIND $positions as props
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Position)
WHERE PROPERTIES(p) = props
CALL {
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NULL
  CREATE (q:Position)
  SET q = $props
  RETURN q AS result
  UNION
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NOT NULL
  RETURN p AS result
}
RETURN ID(result)
```

However, when there are equal properties in the $positions  list, like this:

```
[{symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", location:"zzz", effective: false},
{symbol: "xxx", name: "yyy", location:"zzz", effective: false}]
```

Then, two equal nodes are created. How can I prevent de creation of duplicate nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `WITH DISTINCT props` to get rid of the duplicates:

```
UNWIND $positions as props
WITH DISTINCT props
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Position)
WHERE PROPERTIES(p) = props
CALL {
  WITH p, props
  WITH p, props WHERE p IS NULL
  CREATE (q:Position)
  SET q = props
  RETURN q AS result
  UNION
  WITH p
  WITH p WHERE p IS NOT NULL
  RETURN p AS result
}
RETURN ID(result)
```

This query also fixes a few other issues in your query.

Comment: To supplement, a subquery just after the UNWIND (or after the UNWIND ... WITH DISTINCT) would ensure that the following OPTIONAL MATCH and so on happens per-row, with no opportunity for eager evaluation of OPTIONAL MATCH (for all rows) prior to the later subquery.